# Creating a Sequential Model with a Batch Normalization layer freezes program

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I was trying to figure out how to create a model with Keras. To help me, I'm making use of `plot_model` to visualize the model as I assemble it. The program is just assembling a sequential model and exporting it using `plot_model`.

Everything was working fine until I tried to add a Batch Normalization (BN) layer to the model.

The program suddenly attempts to add a GPU device and freezes. I'm forced to close the program through Task Manager

I'm running this in Windows 10. Python version 3.6. Tensorflow-gpu version 1.12.0. Keras version 2.2.4

I thought I had imported from the wrong library, so I tried referencing it directly. It didn't change anything. I've tried consulting different implementations of BN layers and they all seem to implement them the same way I do without a problem.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU, Activation
import keras

import os


encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(Conv2D(64, (7,7),strides=(2,2), input_shape=(256, 256,3)))
encoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
encoder.add(LeakyReLU())
encoder.add(Conv2D(64, 3, strides=3, padding='same'))


from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(encoder, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)

print ('done')
```

When I run the program, it hangs on this output: `I:tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0` and never outputs the 'done' message. The `plot_model` image doesn't export either.

The above message is also very unusual, as it doesn't show up when any of the other layers are added to the encoder.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use `encoder.summary()`, which will print a textual description of each layer on the console. It should have roughly the same information as the plot you're trying to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading TensorFlow to 1.9 version.

If this does not work, uninstall Keras (and its applications and preprocessing).

Then, in your code, modify all the imports from **keras.models** to **tensorflow.keras.models**; in other words, every import you make, do it **via tensorflow**.

Comment: importing it via tensorflow fixed the problem. I didn't even need to downgrade. Thanks!